# Photoshop cursor disturbs my work

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, adobe-creative-suite

If I [move layers with the cursor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/tool-techniques/move-tool.html):

When I release the cursor, for a second it still holds on to the layer. Usually I let the cursor go, to move the cursor to the menu or a different layer. Because it always still holds on to the previous layer, it moves the layer around for one second. This is extremly annoying because I always need to wait for one second, between each layer movement.

I use a mac with a trackpad (but other programs don't have this problem), with Photoshop CC 2020.

How can I disable this?

Comment: I mean it sounds like a bug or performance issue, which usually don't have an on/off switch. I'd try trashing preferences, doing a clean install and/or updating to the newest version.

Comment: Don't use a trackpad for graphic design software. It's too inaccurate. Get a proper mouse.

Comment: Can't repro here, with auto-select on or off [which I though *might* have some impact], though I don't have a trackpad.

Comment: Could be slow old pc. Could even just be dirt on trackpad – had similar issues that fixed itself only by cleaning my nasty looking trackpad. Could also be that your file is really huge and it just takes a bit to load.

Comment: Late thought, related to 'slow, old PC' - try changing the level of Hardware Acceleration. Photoshop menu >Preferences > Performance. Top right, either switch GPU on or off, or in Advanced Prefs, choose a different 'mode'. Also set your scratch disk to a non-system drive, preferably a spare SSD, not spinny rust. Of course, no matter how good people think their laptops are… they're still laptops & nowhere near as zippy as a big desktop ;)

Comment: Second person I've seen posting about using Adobe apps with a trackpad. Why do you guys _not_ use a mouse ?!

Comment: @Lucian there is a subset of users who think a laptop shall be portable. And carrying a mouse makes it less portable. So for philosophical reasons they use the trackpad. For similar philosophical reasons i do not work on laptops. My work is not portable so my computer needn't be portable either which means that of all my colleagues i have the most ergonomic and most powerful computer, most screenestate more drive and more reliable internet. Even though technically I have the oldest computer. But this only really applies to power workstations since on lower cost end laptops have better bang for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason and some sort of solution:

The reason is that I use "three finger dragging" which you can enable in `mac settings » accessibility » mouse & trackpad`.

If I drag objects the "conventional way" with a physical click and drag (with the trackpad), there is no problem at all. It has nothing to do with the trackpad itself, which btw. works really well in my opinion.

It only appears with the "three finger drag" since there is a small delay, when you release the fingers from the trackpad. The same behaviour is noticeable when you move windows in the "mission control window" (three finger drag vs. conventional drag).

What I really don't understand: This behaviour does not appear in InDesign or Illustrator which I use a lot. That's why I thought, this is some bad setting in photoshop.